# Is "cousin" used broadly for relatives, and can A's cousin's child also be termed A's cousin?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is "cousin" a term for any relative?
For instance, if Person A's mother's sister is B, and B's child is C, then A and C are cousins.
If C has a child, D, would D be considered A's cousin? Is this a standard use of the term "cousin"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not on learning English.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore But it does ask for learning the use of the word `cousin` which is an English word

Comment: Usage of the word "cousin" varies. You would need to check among the people you will be speaking with.

Comment: [Cousin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cousin) has different meanings, one of which is a relative descended from a common ancestor who's not related more closely (i.e. not a brother, aunt, parent, grandparent, child, etc). There are several existing questions about cousins if you search (and more on English Language and Usage).

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore Why don't you think this is about learning English?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222164

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are first/second/third cousins?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222164/what-are-first-second-third-cousins)

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, D is A's *first cousin once removed* (they are of the next generation), and a child of A's would be D's *second cousin*. But it's not usually necessary to be so specific in everyday speech, so they might all refer to one another casually as 'cousins'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any blood relationship that doesn't already have a name without the word "cousin" in it can be called a "cousin".

There are specific terms for every type of cousin, and they all follow the format, *[ "first/second/third/... cousin" (+ "once/twice/three times/... removed") ]*.

> first cousin (person A to person C)
> second cousin twice removed
> etc.

Any of these people can simply be called your "cousin". My second cousin once removed is just "my cousin" to me or anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

In the most common context, "cousin" is a term indicating family relation, specifically the child of a sister, brother, sister in law, or brother in law of either parent.

However there does exist a separate context in which "cousin" can refer to anyone belonging to the same family (in general), culture, or nationality. This context is reminiscent of the similar context of people related in such ways being brothers and sisters. This usage of "cousin" is much less common than the similar usage of "brother" and "sister", but it does exist.

See: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cousin